# How to set default value for new attribute of an Entity when update CoreData Model Version

Tags: core-data, iphonecoredatarecipes

I use CoreData to save my App's data. There is en entity names FriendInfo. Now I update the CoreData Model Version, and add an attribute "isBlock" for FriendInfo, and set the Default value to YES. When I run again the App and insert some FriendInfo, I found the value of new record's attribute "isBlock" is YES(in SQLite the value is 1). But the value of old records are NULL not YES. Who can tell me how to set the default value for old records?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'll have to run some code to update the defaults value. In MSSQL Server and MySQL, default value only applies to new records. We'll have to run SQL to update old records. I think it should be the same case to SQLite

Comment: Very Thx @Jun1st. I think you are right, and I found another way:set the new attribute "isBlock" non-optional. Then after run the App, all exist record's attribute "isBlock" will be set NO.

Comment: maybe you can try delete the column, and add it back again, setting default to "YES" and NOT NULL.  all exist records' "isBlock" should be YES.